# Mapping Linux users/groups to Windows 2019 NFS Share

Tags: linux, centos, nfs, windows-server-2019, centos8

I have a Windows Server 2019 machine and a CentOS 8 machine on the same network.  The CentOS server is hosting a webapp that uses files from the Windows machine.

To read these files, I had set up a Samba share on the Windows side and mounted it on the CentOS side via `mount -t cifs //myserver/share /media/windows`.

This worked, but I noticed some issues.  Sometimes when trying to access files from this Samba share, it would just sit there.  Unmounting and remounting didn't seem to help as the problem would just happen again.

I decided to try using NFS instead of Samba to share files between Windows 2019 and CentOS.  After setting up the same folder, but instead as an NFS share, and using `mount -t nfs myserver:/share /media/windows` I was able to access the files that would make Samba hang.

The issue I am having is that when I make a new file in the NFS share from the CentOS side, the permissions are wrong on the Windows side and users on the Windows server cannot access the files.

I looked into this and tried to set up NFS user mapping, but I don't think I did it right.

Using PowerShell, I ran:

```
Install-NfsMappingStore -InstanceName "NFSMappingStore" -LdapPort 10389
```

and saw:

> Successfully created ADLDS instance named NFSMappingStore on server MYSERVER, the instance is running on port 10389 and the partition is CN=nfs,DC=nfs.

I then ran:

```
Set-NfsMappingStore -EnableLdapLookup $true -LdapNamingContext "CN=nfs,DC=nfs"
    -LdapServer localhost:10389
```

Seeing as that worked, I then tried to add a user:

```
New-NfsMappedIdentity -MappingStore LDAP -Server localhost:10389
    -UserIdentifier 980 -GroupIdentifier 1001
    -UserName CentOsUser -PrimaryGroup "Domain Users"
```

This seemed to work correctly, so then back on the CentOS side, I mounted the NFS share as the `CentOsUser` user via:

```
sudo -u CentOsUser -g CentOsGroup mount -t nfs myserver:/share /media/windows
```

This worked, and I was able to create and write a file.  But on the Windows side, I see that the (newly created) file's owner is actually `S-1-5-88-1-980` instead of `CentOsUser`.

I also see `S-1-5-88-2-1001` as well as `S-1-5-88-3-420` and `S-1-5-88-4`.

Why is it showing `S-1-5-88-1-980`?  I thought I mapped `980` to the `CentOsUser` user?  I also thought I mapped `1001` to the `Domain Users` group, so why is it showing `S-1-5-88-2-1001`?

Comment: `Resolve-NfsMappedIdentity -AccountName "CentOsUser" -AccountType "User"` what does it tell you?

Comment: @AndroidX "Resolve-NfsMappedIdentity : Failed to resolve identity mapping for user windows account CentOsUser. Verify if mapping store is configured on the server." :-(

Comment: How can I "Verify if mapping store is configured on the server?"  I thought I had that set up...

Comment: `Test-NfsMappingStore` and if it exists you should be able to see its config with `Get-NfsMappingStore`

Comment: @AndroidX `Test-NfsMappingStore` shows nothing.

Comment: @AndroidX `Get-NfsMappingStore` shows: `LdapServer: localhost:10389, LdapNamingContext: CN=nfs,DC=nfs, LdapLookupEnabled: True`

Comment: Is that correct?  I used `Install-NfsMappingStore` which set up `ADLDS`.  Is this an LDAP server?  Should be set as the `ADDomain` instead (in `Set-NfsMappingStore`)?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and was struggling with it since a log time...

- Now I intigrated Linux server with AD.
- Managing all files and directory level permissions from Windows
- the application user accessing files from windows NFS share is an AD authenticated user..

Above procedure still working for me.

Comment: How do I add the Linux server to an Active Directory?  Will that affect anything else on the Linux server (it's also a web host)?

Answer (score 0):

The best and easiest solution I found is https://github.com/billziss-gh/sshfs-win, connected servers shows up as a fully functioning network drives

Edit:
Mounting a NTFS Share on Linux

```
mkdir /mnt/win1
mount -t cifs //10.10.1.100/share -o username=myUser,password=myPassword /mnt/win1
```

Comment: Is this just for mapping SSH drives on Windows?  That's pretty useful, but not quite what I needed.  I needed to mount the other direction.  Mount a folder _from_ Windows _on_ Linux.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood, you need to mount with ntfs: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-mount-partition-with-ntfs-file-system-and-read-write-access

Comment: I need to mount a folder from Windows on Linux over the network.  I was using CIFS/Samba but I was having issues.  So, I tried NFS but was having different issues.  I'm not a Windows Server guy, I'm more of a Linux guy.

Comment: @gen_Eric I'll edit my comment with some extra information.